# jquery - get attributes of an element when clicked . The element contains inner divs so getting undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the html code like this :

```
<ul>
  <li k="5" id="l">
    <div>
        <div>
         Some Text
        </div>
    </div>   
  </li>
</ul>
```

From the above code, if I dont have any div's or spans or someother elements inside the **li** tag, then $(e.target).attr("k") will give correct value . But, as it has some other elements inside it, when I click the element, it gives undefined value . What is the solution ?

Comment: Check, whether you are clicking on li or not by using console.log(this) in the event handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to event bubbling. The event is actually firing not on the `li` but on one of its child/descendant elements. Therefore you are actually looking for the `k` attribute of that, not the `li`.

This doesn't happen when there's no child elements as there's no potential for event bubbling - the event will always be triggered only by the `li`.

The simplest way round this is to use `this` inside the event callback rather than `evt.target`.

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    var k = $(this).attr('k');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery `closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - it doesn't rely on a direct parent.

Answer (score 0):

I get the correct answer by running this:

```
 $(function(){
     $("li").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("k"));                
     });
 });​
```

Comment: That's precisely what I answered :)

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
$(e.target).closest("li").attr("k");
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute can be obtained in the following way

```
$(e.target).closest("li").attr("k");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
$('li').('click', function() {
  var k = $(this).attr('k');
});
```